# Can you @autowire a field in static child class from spring boot 1.5.9

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, lombok

I was given a really REALLY old project at work

I usually don't have a problem google cant figure out for me

This is a massive code base and I'm in charge of fixing it

The original author created a class and inside that class created a static child class

example

```
public class parent {
   public static class child {
   }
}
```

inside that static child class I am hoping to @Autowire a repo already created and working fine

I am the first to admit I don't know everything but from what i understand

If the spring framework can find the component

It should be able to inject it's dependency

For example:

```
@component
public class parent {

   @component
   public static class child {

        @autowired
        private SomeRepo repo;
   }
}
```

But clearly I'm wrong about that

I'm really really trying to avoid using jdbctemplate because from what I'm reading so far
it bypasses and duplicates a connection that should be managed by Spring

But I am struggling to autowire this repo for accessing the database

Please help

I have tried attaching the @component, @entity, JDBCTemplate Im hoping to avoid
I have also tried Autowiring up the channel that calls it and sending it in the function of the static class that needs it

I have been reading and cant find an answer yet

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question but its very specific to this project

In the end I found a class up the inheritance and used the injection functionality there and passed it in to the static class

I don't know if that is the best way but it seems to be working

I'm open to comments on how i can improve this code solution